# Get click event for Graphics in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, charts

We are writing  a text in an image using `System.Drawing.Graphics.Drawstring`. Below code is shown

```
        Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"D:\ABC\Chart1.png");
        Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
        //Smooth graphics is nice.
        graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        String drawString = "250";
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12,FontStyle.Bold);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        PointF drawPoint= new PointF(169.0F, 85.0F); .

        graphicImage.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);

        //Set the content type
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        //Save the new image to the response output stream.
        bitMapImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        //Clean house.
        graphicImage.Dispose();
        bitMapImage.Dispose();
```

The code takes an imagefile and writes the string (here:250).Now when user clicks 250, the new window should get open.

Not sure how to get the click event of 250?

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to render the image to a container like a DIV or SPAN, and add an onclick to container:

```
<div onclick="doSomething();">
    <!-- rendered image here -->
</div>
```

You might also look into using an Image Map, like this:

```
function foo() {
 alert("Hello World!")
}

<img src="/images/someimage.png" usemap="#somemap" />
<map name="somemap">
    <area coords="0,0,82,126" onclick="foo()" nohref="true" href="#" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ASP.NET detecting a click on drawn text in an image is possible but far from ideal. You should instead render text using a div or other html element by positioning it over the image and detect clicks on the that instead using javascript.

See [Text Blocks Over Image](http://css-tricks.com/3118-text-blocks-over-image/)